# I don't know what the output code is. The compiler says there is an invalid character in identifier of line 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
b = 0
for a in range(0, 10, 2):
    b += a − 1 
print(a," ",b)
```

I am practicing on a past paper. Please help. And can someone please explain 
the break and continue functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character `−` is not a correct python identifier for minus operator, you need `-` instead:

```
>>> 3 − 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3 − 1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
>>> 
>>> 3 - 1
2
```

It's actually a unicode with code point 8722:

```
>>> ord('−')
8722
```